# XSL transformation failing due to invalid formatting?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to remove the characters `NO` from the `cbc:ID` element, but only in the files where these characters are found.

```xml
<cbc:ID>NO123456789</cbc:ID>
```

Should become:

```
<cbc:ID>123456789</cbc:ID>
```

I have made some progress, but run into a wall, and I can see what I'm doing wrong. The Notepad++ XML Tools plugins complain about the XSL being invalid.

The XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>31</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
        <cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
            <cbc:ID>NO60210517971</cbc:ID>
        </cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
    </cac:PaymentMeans>
</Invoice>
```

The XSL file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    
    <xsl:template match="cac:PaymentMeans">

        <Invoice version="1.0"
            xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
            xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
            xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
            xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <cac:PaymentMeans>
                <cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
                    <cbc:ID>
                        <xsl:variable name="accountnumber" select="cac:PayeeFinancialAccount/cbc:ID"/>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="contains($accountnumber, 'NO'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="translate($accountnumber, 'NO', '')"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$accountnumber"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </cbc:ID>
                </cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
            </cac:PaymentMeans>
        </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis on line 23 of your XSLT. Should be : contains($accountnumber, 'NO').

Comment: @Sebastien Thank you so much! Must have stared myself blind...

Comment: My advice : From my experience the messages in Notepad++ are cryptic and it's hard to develop in XSLT in Notepad++. Get some XSLT development tool, or use https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ or simply use Saxon on the command line.

Comment: Note that you could do simply `<xsl:value-of select="translate(cac:PayeeFinancialAccount/cbc:ID, 'NO', '')"/>` without testing.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That would work on this example, but one example does not constitute a specification...

Comment: @MichaelKay I took *"remove the characters `NO`"* as the specification.

Comment: Yes, but your solution also removes "N" or "O" or "ON", and we don't know whether that's OK.

Comment: @MichaelKay If it's not OK, then the specification is not what OP stated. Note that OP's own solution will remove single "N" and "O" characters from strings that contain the combination "NO" anywhere in the string - for example, "N1234NO56O78" will become "12345678".

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of your requirement "I'm trying to remove the characters NO from the cbc:ID element..." is the stylesheet solution below.
There is only one replacement necessary, the rest can be handled by a copy template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="//cbc:ID" priority="2">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'NO','')"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here's the result when the xslt is applied to your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
   xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2"
   xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2"
   xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <cac:PaymentMeans>
      <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>31</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
      <cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
         <cbc:ID>60210517971</cbc:ID>
      </cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
   </cac:PaymentMeans>
</Invoice>
```